# Android: How to visually indicate barcode scanning capability in an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, zxing

I have an Android app that has several `EditText` items with barcode scanning ability (user long-holds and ZXing intent is invoked).

What I need to do is to visually indicate to the user that this item has the barcode scanner ability attached, but I have not been able to find a "standard" way of doing this which makes it obvious to the casual user. I don't want my app to be out of step with how everyone else does it, trouble is there does not seem to be a standard way of doing it, or if there is I can't find it!

My approach is to have a new style which changes the background color, the border or the font, or add a drawable image to the `EditText`. Can anyone make some suggestions?

Comment: As a "casual user", I would never expect an EditText to have scan ability. I would suggest a button (probably image or text) next to the EditText will trigger that scanning.

Comment: OK so what I am doing may not be a standard Design Pattern for a mobile device. But IMHO the cleaner a screen is on a mobile app the better, and I would like to invoke a barcode scanner via a gesture rather than a button. And if I add in OCR capablility that's more buttons. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Well, to me, long press is always not preferred, it is trouble(take 2-3 seconds to trigger that action), not intuitive, and requiring extra tutorial/help to let user know about this hidden feature. You are right about cleaner screen, but being not confused is most important. Oh, BTW, how did the long press distinguish scan/OCR? Context menu popup?

Comment: another possible solution just popout: an custom keyboard. Tap on EditText, normally a keyboard is shown, but replaced with your custom one, with those scan/ocr buttons in-place... This sounds closer to the UI custom of Android

Answer (score 1):

Look at Google Product search on a mobile device. The search bar has a barcode button which launches the Barcode Scanner app. I'd suggest this is a pretty fine precedent to follow.

Comment: Thanks Sean. I don't like the Google Product Search approach, if I have 5 EditText items on a screen, thats an extra 5 buttons (or 10 if I have separate OCR buttons) to fit in somehow. Clutter.
xandy - I love the custom keyboard idea, nice clean UI, it neatly fixes the problem of indicating to users that barcode scanning is available, and its infinitely extendable for new input methods. I will experiment, thanks for the help